# How do I wait for a timer to elapse before continuing a for loop?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using regular foreach loop, and I want to wait until the timer finishes before continuing to the next case. How do I do that?

```
foreach (int i in TimeImage)
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(showImage);
    timer1.Interval = i * 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    showImage();
}
```

Comment: You mean to start the second timer after first completed and so on? Is your timer recurring timer? If so what is the definition of completion?

Comment: After first time is finished

Comment: I guess choosing the right "Timer"-class could solve your problem. If you're new to this topic, this could be a good start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx. For your scenario maybe the "System.Threading.Timer" could work with the parameter specifying no interval (means it gets called only one time). As I not fully understand your goal, maybe executing the timing on a different thread and using "Thread.Sleep" on that thread might get you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding of what you want is correct (show the images in a certain sequence) then the for-loop might not work the way you want it to. the timer would not block the loop - which is how it was intended anyway.

*you wouldn't want to block your UI this way (or at all).

since you are already assigning a timer for each image, just separate the assignment of the interval from the start into two for-loops.

```
List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>(); 
//i'm assuming that TimeImage is a list? 
for (int i=1; i<=TimeImage.Count(); i++)
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(showImage); 
    timer1.Interval = i * 1000;
    timers.add(timer1); 
    //note showimage should know which particular image is to be loaded 
    //showimage should also stop the last timer that was triggered 
}

foreach (Timer atimer in timers)
{
    atimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: I have a few images and for each one different time for showing. I must wait until timer elapse for first one and then show second one with a different time

Comment: I updated the code so it would correctly use different intervals, but another suggestion would to lay out the sequence in the timer's Tick eventhandler. When the Tick event is triggered, start the next timer.. AND don't forget to stop the previous timer.